# Firebase Security Rules Nested $ Variables

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

In my Firebase database I have a node `eventdata` contains a list of data elements related to a certain event.
Each event item has an `event_log` node where all the logging of that certain event is done.

The goal is to allow users only access to part of the `event_log` items. (e.g. the items they created themselves)

When the respective part in the Security Rules looks like this, everything works fine, but no access control on individual items is possible.

```
"eventdata":{
    "$event":{
        "event_log":{
            ".read": " auth != null",
            ".write":" auth != null"
         }
    }
}
```

Changing the code such that it uses another $ variable (but still should allow access from all authenticated users) results in not being able to access the `event_log`.

```
"eventdata":{
    "$event":{
        "event_log":{
           "$logitem":{
            ".read": " auth != null",
            ".write":" auth != null"
           }
         }
    }
}
```

Isn't it possible to 'nest' $ variables in the Security API? I couldn't find an answer to this in the Firebase Docs. Is there any other solution other than having to restructure my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What rights are you granting on `$event` itself? Can you edit the question to include those (if any)?

Comment: Currently not granting any rights on the `$event` itself, but on all childs of each `$event`. The two code blocks indicate the difference that causes the same client code to execute successfully in the first case, and throws a "permission denied" error in the second case.

Comment: You can certainly nest $ variables and this is a [common approach](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html#section-revisiting-advanced-example). However, your underlying question (see [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)) seems to be about filtering data. And you [cannot use security rules as a filter](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter).

Comment: Thanks for your response Kato. I understand now that I should not use security rules to filter out data. But shouldn't the two codeblocks in my initial question be functionally equivalent? In both cases I allow access to all the event logs if the user is authorized.
But when nesting $ vars it gives permission errors.